# How to assign different record types to different users of the same profile

Tags: profile, record-type

I have a scenario:
There are two groups of users in the same profile, Group A and Group B.
I have two Record Types on a custom object, say R1 and R2.
The Record Type R1 is the record type assigned to this profile.

The requirement is as: Group A must have **only** R1 record type and Group B must have **only** R2 record type assigned to it. It means that while creating a new record, Group A users must be able to create a record of type R1 **only** and Group B users must be able to create a record of type R2 **only**.

**I tried this**:
Create a permission set with R2 record type assigned to it. Add all the Group B users to this permission set. Now, users of Group B will have the option to select from R1 and R2 at the time of creating a new record. But I want that Group B users must be able to create a record of type R2 and not R1.

**One Possible solution is**:
Clone this profile, assign R2 record type to it and add all the Group B users to this profile. But I don't want to increase the number of profiles in my org.

Is there any other possible solution?

Comment: What's the difference between the recordtypes? Are the page layouts for new records different? If not, you might put the recordtype assignment in a workflow rule.

Comment: Yes, the page layouts assigned to both the record types are different. So a workflow would not serve the purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

- Create permission set P1 with record type R1 only assigned to it
- Create permission set P2 with record type R2 only assigned to it
- Add P1 or P2 to the appropriate Users
- Ensure R1 and R2 are not set on the profile, leaving just the Master record type selected there

Then when the SObject is created it is automatically given the record type according to the permission set of the user (with no record type selection prompt) which is the behaviour I believe you want.

Comment: Thanks Keith. I tried it and yes, it meets my requirement.

Answer (score 0):

[Sharing Rules](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=security_about_sharing_rules.htm&language=en_US) would allow you to do this. You could add two sharing rule on the object that you want. The sharing rules would share based on the record type. See the example below where contacts are being shared with 2 groups. You would need to do something similar

[image]

Comment: Thanks Bar.
Actually my requirement is not about sharing of records, it deals with the creation of records. That means that while creating a new record, the Group A users must be able to create a record of type R1 by default and Group B users must be able to create a record of type R2 by default.

Comment: @user7290 it would be worth updating your question with that information.